# Bash: Find the disk a certain partition is on and put result into a variable

Tags: bash, variables, partitioning, disk, block-device

What are some (reliable) tests to find the disk a certain partition is on and put that result into a variable?

For example, output of `lsblk`:

```
...
sda           8:0    0   9.1T  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0   9.1T  0 part /foopath
...
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /barpath
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.5G  0 part /foobarpath
```

If `partition="/dev/mmcblk0p2"`, how can I put `mmcblk0` as the disk it is a part of into a variable? Or similarly, if `partition="/dev/sda1"`, how to put `sda` as the disk it is a part of into a variable?

`disk=${partition::-1}` seemed to be a hack until I encountered partitions such as `mmcblk0p1`, hence the request for a more reliable test...

The purpose of isolating the disk and using variable is to pass it to `smartctl -n standby /dev/sda` to find if disk is currently spinning, etc.

Operating environment is Linux Mint 19.3 and Ubuntu 20.

Any ideas?

Comment: So extract part of the string between the last `/` and the first digit?

Comment: I believe the OP wants the strings extracted as per the disk names, like: `mmcblk0` and `sda`...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if pattern matching is the way to go since it seems the disk names can vary structure? I'm not certain of that though. Finding the "root" name of the drive is what I'm after (like in `lsblk` output above). Hope that helps clear it up!

Comment: `is to pass it to smartctl` just pass `/dev/sda1`, it will pick the disc by itself. @edit ok, so seems to depend on the disc, works for my partitions as far as I could tell.

Comment: Nah that doesn't work for me for partitions. `smartctl` seems to want the disk. i.e. `smartctl -n standby /dev/sda` returns `Device is in IDLE_A mode` but .../sda1 doesn't.

Comment: Here is the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226420/how-to-get-disk-name-that-contains-a-specific-partition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @KamilCuk and [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226426/429762) ;)

"Print just the parent device" using `lsblk`

```
#!/bin/bash
partition="/dev/sda1"
disk="$(lsblk -no pkname "${partition}")"
```